# Why does this http request time out?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, openshift, fetch-api

I am sending a GET request inside an OpenShift pod to a backend application. In the console of the openshift pod I can run the following command **succesfully**:

```
wget -qO- --no-check-certificate \
--header 'Accept: */*' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded auth>' \
https://my-url.nl:8221/path/to/my/resource/organisations
```

I can also call the API endpoint from postman without issue (from a different server).

However, when I run the following fetch I get a timeout.

```js
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';

const credentials = Buffer.from(
  `USERNAME:PASSWORD`
).toString('base64');

fetch(
  'https://my-url.nl:8221/path/to/my/resource/organisations',
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`,
      Accept: '*/*',
    },
  }
).then((data) => {
  console.log(data.json());
}).catch((reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
});
```

I get the following error after a long wait

```
GET https://my-url.nl:8221/path/to/my/resource/organisations net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Both the preflight and actual API call fail.

Am I forgetting something simple? Does this have to do with CORS? Or something with skipping the certificate validation? What kind of API call would return a timeout rather than a failed (400/500) response.

Comment: is the code executed at `https://my-url.nl:8221/path/to/my/resource/organisations` something you've written?

Comment: Have you by any chance sent invalid request's / credentials to the URL, if so you might be temporally banned, some systems will not even respond to requests when in this state, as it can help mitigate DOS attacks.  But saying this, if you can do Postman from the same machine that won't be it.

Comment: It could also be an issue with `fetch` in nodejs, are you using the experimental `fetch`, or is `fetch` some library you added to nodejs? it's clear you don't actually know how to use fetch, since `console.log(data.json());` will always log out a Promise

Comment: @JaromandaX This url / endpoint was created by my colleagues.

Comment: @Keith I am 100% certain that the credentials are correct. I am not banned from calling the API. I can sucessfully call the API from the OpenShift console, which is the same environment as the JavaScript code.

Comment: @JaromandaX  Looking at his console logs he has shown, this looks more like from the browser, rather than node.  But looking at his code, it looks like Node,  what's going on here OP, can you explain?

Comment: @Keith - good point ... the `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` looks nodejs ... `Buffer.from` looks nodejs ... I hadn't even looked at the pictures OP posted ... because pictures rarely help :p and yet pre-flight indicates browser

Comment: `was created by my colleagues` - have you asked them what you're doing wrong?

Comment: What do those screenshots (from a browser) have to do with your question (which shows node.js code)? Side note: CORS is a browser thing, you would see a message about it in the JS console of the browser.

Comment: Because you have node code, your obviously compiling this, otherwise `Buffer.from` would not work.  As such are you using something like `node-fetch`?,  the compiler will try it's best to polyfill into browser code, but it might not be 100%, eg. do you have something like this in your code -> `import fetch from 'node-fetch';`  If you want a `fetch` that works `node` & `browser` you might want to look at -> https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch that will use the native fetch for each platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the comments & answers to my post. It made me question how I was calling the endpoint. I am working with NextJs (React framework). This allows you to perform API calls, either client side or server side. I was performing these calls client side rather than server side (which won't work). The solution is to use the NextJs GetServerSideProps function.

My full working solution for anyone interested:

```js
import { PageLayoutWithSideMenu } from '@pcss-cargonaut/ui-lib';
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';

type Organisation = {
  accountNumber: number;
  accountSequenceNumber: number;
  name: string;
  role: string;
};
type Organisations = Organisation[];

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
  process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';

  const credentials = Buffer.from(
    `USERNAME:PASSWORD`
  ).toString('base64');

  const res = await fetch(
    'https://my-url.nl:8221/path/to/my/resource/organisations',
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`,
        Accept: '*/*',
      },
    }
  );

  const organisations: Organisations = await res.json();

  return { props: { organisations } };
};

const Organizations = ({ organisations }: { organisations: Organisations }) => {
  console.log(organisations);

  return (
    <PageLayoutWithSideMenu>
      ...
    </PageLayoutWithSideMenu>
  );
};

export default Organizations;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply not going to work if you're doing it from the browser, as seen in the photos.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
```

These two lines do nothing in the browser. They only work in a NodeJS environment.

The only way to make it work is to change the backend endpoint, to a valid SSL cert (not self-signed). The easiest way to do that is probably cloudflare.

EDIT: I suspect you're compiling this from Node via react, vue, etc. In that case, it absolutely won't work because `process.env` is setting a system environment variable. Browsers don't have environment variables, so this isn't going to work, those 2 lines will do nothing.

Comment: yet, that code runs, as the fetch is initiated ... curious

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a promise that resolves with a Response object and the `response.json()` returns, in turn, another promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as JSON.

So, you have to add another `.then()` after the first one.

A general example below:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```